# Handling variable Path Parameter in Python FastApi

Tags: python, rest, get, fastapi

I'm trying to write a simple get request for my Angular Frontend in FastApi

i've created this endpoint with the parameter of the item_id:

```
@app.get("/pokemon/{item_id}")
async def getPokemon(item_id: int):
    response = pokemon.getPokemon()
    return response
```

and in the getPokemon() i go to the official Api and make the get Request:

```
def getPokemon():
    response = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{item_id}'),
    pokemonOutput = json.loads(response.text)
    return pokemonOutput
```

My Question is, if i make the request to my endpoint and send the item_id parameter from the frontend with it. How can i make it so the item_id is passed as variable in the url of the get Request to the official API?

I can't seem to find anything by googling.
Thx for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just modify the function

```
def get_pokemon(item_id):
    response = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+item_id),
    pokemonOutput = json.loads(response.text)
    return pokemonOutput
```

and call it from you're endpoint

Comment: .. and you'd call it by passing the `item_id` in your view function: `response = pokemon.getPokemon(item_id)`. (another small note to OP: You'd usually use `get_pokemon` or just `pokemon` as the method name in Python, not camelcased like `getPokemon` (as in JS or Java).

Comment: yes my bad for the method name